# Raspberry only response to IPv4 ping

Tags: networking, pi-4, raspberry-pi-os, ipv6

I have a Raspberry 4. It is setup with the Raspberry OS. Everything works fine. No errors. But there is still one issue and i am not sure by what it is caused.

I found out the IP-adress of my Raspberry through the router. If I want to ping this IPv4-address it works and the raspberry responds. If i ping the IPv6-address there is no response of the the Raspberry.

Hope someone can help me out of this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it have an ipv6 address?

Comment: @SteveRobillard Yeah, Router displays it on the dashboard & also when I type in ip -6 addr it appears also there.

Comment: If it is a link-local IPv6 address (starts fe80::) then you need to ping from a device within that subnet. Noting that wireless routers often having a setting to prevent devices on the same subnet from communicating. Also check that the file /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf is empty

Comment: Are there any IPv6 firewall rules in place? Check `ip6tables-save` to see the current output of active rules.

Comment: What do you get from `sudo ip -6 addr show`? Are you using a globally routable address or a FD00:: link local address?